# Custom Web property to refresh a webpart for 60 secs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a visual web part where in i want to refresh this webpart for every 60 secs. Can any one give me an example of building a custom webpart property . This should be similar like OOB  Webpart AJAx options.

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would suffice.

http://mmman.itgroove.net/2011/05/adding-an-auto-refresh-content-editor-web-part/

You can register the javascript on the page several ways.

Personally i would put this in the content editor web part and update the time as and when you need.

The below code is for a web part property.

```
[WebBrowsable(true)] 
[WebDisplayName("Message")] 
[WebDescription("Message to display to users")] 
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)] 
[Category("Message Configuration")] 
public string Message 
{ 
    get; set; 
}
```

You might also want to look in to the updatepanel control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope this helps